# Verification of calling address

Tags: solidity

So i have two smart contract contract A and contract B. Now i need to call the function in contract b from contract a but only contract a can call that funtion and no other contract or user so how can i check that only contract a is calling that function.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I guess a normal `require()` check will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your contract B, specify:

`require(msg.sender == "0xCONTRACT_A_ADDR");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
contract a {

function callFuncContractB (address contractAddress) external returns(uint256) {
    b contractB = b(contractAddress);
    uint256 contractBCount = contractB.testCallByA();
    return contractBCount;
   }
}
contract b {

address private contractA;
uint256 public testCount;

constructor (address aAddress) {
    contractA = aAddress;
   }

function testCallByA () public  returns(uint256) {
   require(msg.sender == contractA,"Not allowed");
   testCount += 1 ;
   return testCount;
   }
}
```

this a simple contract that contract a calls contract b function and change state variable with name of `testCount` .
You should enter `contract a` `Address` when you want to deploy `b` inside `constructor`.

Comment: But i can't because i am deploying b before a so no address of a would be available

Comment: If you using testnet network, just try it again first deploy `a` then deploy `b` and enter `a` for `b` deployment, finally call `callFuncContractB` with address of contract `b`.

Comment: I've test it just now, it works.